# What causes striped visual artifacts in models?

Tags: faces, artifacts

I don't know the legitimate term for them, but I'm referring to the "shaded" or "stripy" regions that appear that can appear in your models (see the picture below)

Here is a contrived example deliberately created to reproduce the artifacts:

[image]

1. What are these artifacts called? I did a few google searches to learn more about this but came up short because I can only describe them as "visual artifacts" which is too broad.
2. What is causing these artifacts to appear? In both cases there are overlapping faces, but what causes Blender to show them in the way that it does? To approach from another angle: why could Blender not "simply" ignore overlapping faces?
3. Are there general strategies one would take to fixing these issues? If so, what?

Even a link to a resource that explains this would be appreciated.

Comment: It's called z-fighting and is caused by overlapping faces as you've discovered yourself. Blender can't ignore overlapping faces because there is no way to know which particular face should be used and they have the same depth in z-buffer. The solution is to not create overlapping faces. Sounds stupid/obvious, but that's how it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deepth coordinate during deepth testing made by graphic pipeline is the same.
1 has flipped normals + Z fighting. 
2 is just Z fighting. 
Here is more literature:
https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Depth-testing
 Read "Z-fighting" in the middle of a page.