# Remove drop shadow from label?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, shaders, shadows

I'm completely new to blender, I'm trying to create a simple label for a product as an exercise.

[image: Drop shadow removal from label]

When I use the shrinkwrap modifier to the face of the object in Cycles I get a drop shadow that doesn't appear in Eevee.

I have tried UV Unwrapping as well, and I get the same result.

**Q:** Is there an easy way to remove this shadow for the label?

Comment: There is a problem when you add two surfaces on top of each other. It is called Z-fighting. Read https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/155086/what-causes-striped-visual-artifacts-in-models/155089#155089. instead of adding a new mehs on top the other use Textures and masks, as sugested below.

Answer (score 1):

The more direct fix is to make your outer material have a mask between the metallic label, and the glass or whatever sub-material it lays upon. This also lets you skip the Shrinkwrap modifier because it uses the UV coordinates to wrap the texture around the object.

For example:[image]

This will blend the **Metallic** and **Color** Principled shaders depending on the strength of your mask. In my case, I had a zig zag pattern lying around:

[image]

This way you have less geometry, you have very sharp control over the position & pattern using the same image texture as before, and you can make changes on the same material graph.

Answer (score 0):

The easy fix:
[image]

Do that for your logo. However you should really consider rendering out your logo and use it as a texture on the bottle, you'll have fewer polies and less problems.
The reason this didn't happen in Eevee btw.: Eevees shadows are less precise and only get casted from lamps, not environment or bounced light. They either weren't created or so small that they disappeared.

Comment: i did try this unclicking this box and it made no difference to the render 
however i will look at adding as a texture. Many thanks for taking the time to reply
mike

Comment: thanks this worked - the issue was caused by the inner liquids IOR setting being too high
appreciate your input Frederik